# MVC Stream Picture rotated

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, graphics

I want to use a rotated Image in an MVC Application.
For this purpose i worte an Controller which Returns a rotated Image, but I cant get it working.

This is my Command:

```
public ActionResult PictureStreamRotate(string filename)
{
    Image image = Image.FromFile(filename);
    image.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate90FlipNone);

    MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
    image.Save(stream, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
    return File(stream, "image/jpeg");
}
```

The Image which is streamed back is invalid. Dies anyone have any Idea.
The Input Picture is a `JPG` File.

btw. even if i remove thw line `Image.RotateFlip` it wont work.

Answer (score 1):

This happens because the stream's position is after the written data. `ToArray()` get's everything in the stream from the start. Alternatively, you could set `Position` to zero or `Seek` back to the start of your image data.

Try this in LinqPad:

```
var x = new MemoryStream();
x.WriteByte(123);
x.ReadByte().Dump();
```

It gives `-1` as a result...

Then with `x.Position=0;`and you get the `123` back.

BTW, `ToArray()` copies the data, which is not what you want, I guess.